# Getting Data from JSON - next value every time

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am really trying to get data from my json file while the user parsing on the button but it doesn’t work… any help?
New with Ionic
Thanks

**my ts.**

```
 private tips: any[];
  getData() {
    let localData = this.http.get('/assets/advices.json').map(res => res.json());
    localData.subscribe(data =>{
    this.tips=data;

    })
```

**my html**

```
<button ion-fab (click)="getData()">
    <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
</button>
</ion-content>
```

including the right providers

Answer (score 0):

`http.get` does not directly return the value of the HTTP request, but instead sends the request and returns to the next JS statement immediately before an answer as arrived. You have to subscribe to the method and get the result in the subscription method.

Look into https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/#usage.